# Django + ReactJS. The Httponly cookie is not saved in the browser at React side. I also gave {withcredentials : true} at both side

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios, jwt

I use django rest_framework_simplejwt package to generate JWT tokens and set them in browsable cookie with Httponly flag. At the Django side it work perfectly but at react side it does not work perfectly.
I read many answers related to this question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42188260/django-cookies-are-not-getting-saved-on-browser) and [this](https://github.com/SimpleJWT/django-rest-framework-simplejwt/issues/71) but they have not solved my problem yet.
Please help me understand where I'm wrong.

**DJANGO SIDE**

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
from django.conf import settings

from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework_simplejwt.exceptions import TokenError,\
    InvalidToken
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)

        try:
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        except TokenError as e:
            raise InvalidToken(e.args[0])
           
          # set access token in browser with Httponly cookie.
        res = Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        access_token = serializer.validated_data['access']
        res.set_cookie("access_token", access_token, max_age=settings.SIMPLE_JWT.get('ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME').total_seconds(),samesite='Lax',secure=False, httponly=True)
        
        return res
```

**authentication.py**

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication    
from django.conf import settings

class CookieHandlerJWTAuthentication(JWTAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        # If cookie contains access token, put it inside authorization header
        access_token = request.COOKIES.get('access_token')
        if(access_token):
            request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = '{header_type} {access_token}'.format(
                header_type=settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_HEADER_TYPES'][0], access_token=access_token)

        return super().authenticate(request)
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import MyTokenObtainPairView

urlpatterns = [
    ......
    path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    # path('auth/', include('djoser.urls.jwt')),
    
    path('auth/api/token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
]
```

**settings.py**

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
)
```

**Work perfectly(Token set in cookie with Httponly.):**
[image]

**REACTJS SIDE**

**Login.js**

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
const Login = () => {

const [ivalue, setValue] = useState({});
const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Authcontext);
.......

const loginClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoader(true);

    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/api/token/', {
        username: ivalue.username,
        password: ivalue.password,
    })
        .then((res) => {
            setValue({ password: "" });

            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            });

            setLoader(false);
 
            history.push("/my_profile");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setLoader(false);
            setOpen({ act: true, msg: "error" });

            dispatch({
                type: LOGIN_ERROR,
            });
            setError(err.response.data);
        });
};
.........
};
```

**Myprofile.js**

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

const MyProfile = () => {

    const history = useHistory();
    const { state, dispatch } = useContext(Authcontext);

    useEffect(() => {
        const auth_check = () => {
                axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/users/me/')
                    .then((res) => {
                        dispatch({
                            type: AFTER_LOGIN,
                            payload: res.data
                        });
                    })
                    .catch((err) => {
                        history.push('/login')
                    });
                    };
        auth_check();
    }, []);
}
.......
```

**JWT Response(cookie not set in browser).**
[image]

**Unauthorized Error**
[image]

Comment: Hi there, I'm facing the same problem. I'm fetching (and serving) `localhost` in React but the issue is still there.

Comment: @CoronelV See here your problem answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66952449/14131913

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I set backend and frontend under same IP. ex. my backend is

> localhost:8000

and frontend is

> localhost:3000

different ports same Ip.

**This is not the scenario when it goes to production you can have any domain.**

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a samesite=Lax value in your set-cookie header try using `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True, SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True, CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None', SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'None'`
this will let browser to set cookies even from a different domain.
and use `withCredentials: true` on your client side.