# Django REST and React - JWT Cookie not getting set in browser but working with postman

Tags: reactjs, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, react-redux

Hey guys I am stuck trying to solve the issue with django `set_cookie`, I can't find the cookie in the browser and it doesn't work but works with postman. I went through some of the SO answers and found that I had to provide `withCredentials:true` in the frontend and I have done that, but still it doesn't work. This is the code I have, can someone tell me the error in this?

I want to have the cookies set at login, as of now I am storing the token in local storage and I came to know it is not a safe option.

```
def post(self, request, format=None):
    data            = request.data
    response        = Response()
    username        = data.get('username', None)
    password        =  data.get('password', None)

    user            = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            data    = get_tokens_for_user(user)
            response.set_cookie(
                key     = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE'],
                value   = data["access"],
                expires = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME'],
                secure  = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SECURE'],
                httponly = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_HTTP_ONLY'],
                samesite = settings.SIMPLE_JWT['AUTH_COOKIE_SAMESITE']
            )
            csrf.get_token(request)
            response.data = {"Response": "Login Successful", "data":data,}
            return response
        else:
            return Response({"error": "User is not active"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    else:
        return Response({"error": "Invalid credentials"}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

react front-end

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axiosInstance
        .post(url, {
            username: formData.username,
            password: formData.password,
        })
       // .then((res) => {
       //     localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access);
       //     localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh);
        //    })
        .then(()=> {
            history.push('/');
            window.location.reload(); 
        })
};
```

axiosInstance

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
baseURL: baseURL,
timeout: 5000,
headers: {
    // Authorization: localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    //     ? 'JWT ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token')
    //     : null,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    accept: 'application/json',

},
withCredentials: true
});
```

Thank you.

Comment: Hey Danny..Please tell me your django server url and react url with port no.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.
`django server: http://127.0.0.1:8000/` and react `localhost:3000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set backend and frontend under **same IP**. ex. backend is

> localhost:8000

```
py manage.py runserver localhost:8000
```

and frontend is(By default):

> localhost:3000

**different ports same Ip**.

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65343097/14131913)

Comment: Thank you. I will check it out.

Comment: It worked finally. Thanks a lot.  cheers!

Comment: Use this : `axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = Jwt ${token}`

Comment: Okay. but can you tell me what difference does it make? or is this the preferred way? thanks

Comment: No any difference between them but It's simplest way to pass JWT token for every request..

Comment: Ok. Thanks again for your time and help!