# Cookies not being stored in browser

Tags: reactjs, django, next.js

Working with `Next.js` and `Django Rest Framework`, I'm authenticating users using JWT. First, when the user successfully logs in to the page, a cookie (which contains the JWT token) is sent to the browser. When the user tries to access a specific page, this cookie is used to validate the petition. I'm having trouble storing the cookie in the browser.

Django | login function

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def login(request):
 ...

response = Response()
response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True, max_age=86400)
response.data ={
    'message': 'success',
}
return response
```

And here is how I'm fetching /api/login

Next | Login.js

```
        var axios = require('axios');
        var FormData = require('form-data');
        var data = new FormData();
        data.append('email', this.state.email);
        data.append('password', this.state.password);
        data.append('X-CSRFToken', csrftoken);
        data.append('mode', 'same-origin');
        data.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        
        var config = {
            method: 'post',
            credentials: 'include', #I'm probably having issues with this
            url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/login',
            data : data
        };

        axios(config)
        .then(res=> {
          console.log('success'); #I got logged, but cookie is not stored
        })
        .catch(
            error=>{this.setState({isError:true})}
        );
```

Here is the set-cookie in the browser:
[image: Browser network tap catpure]
[image: resposne information]

But `JWT` is missing on storage:
[image: storage tab from browser]

As you can see, in both of them I'm receiving the cookie named JWT. But it's not being stored in the browser.
Thank you in advance for your time and answers!

Comment: Yes, i can see `Set-Cookie`, I've updated the question.

Comment: is the cookie secure?

Comment: @UdenduAbasili checking cookies tab in Postman, `JWT` cookie appears as not secure but `HttpOnly = True`. How can I secure this cookie? I'd like to see if this solves my problem

Comment: no secure cookies only work when the website uses ssl which i would assume your website doesnt use. I want to confirm because this can be an issue sometime if you use secure true for a non secure website

Comment: i'm not using SSL, currently working on localhost

Comment: You can setup https for local host as secure cookies are only valid for https.
You can follow this guide if you are on ubuntu
https://medium.com/internshala-tech/adding-self-trusted-ssl-certificate-for-localhost-on-ubuntu-nginx-c66d70b22e4b

Answer (score 2):

It's **important** to note is that `mode`, `credentials` aren't supported for configuring `Axios`.It works in `fetch api` because those options are part of the `Request API` (docs for mode are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode)).

Axios uses a [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) under the hood, not [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request).

**Try this** :

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('email', this.state.email);
data.append('password', this.state.password);

const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
}

var config = {
    method: 'post',
    withCredentials: true,
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/api/login',
    data : data,
    {headers: headers}
};

axios(config)
.then(res=> {
  console.log('success');
})
.catch(
    error=>{this.setState({isError:true})}
);
```

------------------------------OR----------------------------------

**put this at top**:

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = "X-CSRFTOKEN";
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = "csrftoken";
```

This Must in django:

**settings.py**:

```
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',
    'http://localhost:8000'
)
```

Comment: I've tried the second option (I'm having an issue with the first one, probably a typo in `config ={ ..., data: data, {headers:headers} } ;` ?. But the `JWT` cookie is not stored in the browser yet

Comment: @CoronelV Use first option and set `samesite=None` in `response.set_cookie('jwt', token, max_age=31449600, samesite=None, secure=False)`...Please note that setting a cookie with `samesite=None` is dangerous so it should be set with `secure=True` at production env.